# Gradient Descent for dual hinge loss function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to solve the problem of training a binary classification problem with target variables {-1, 1} using the dual-hinge loss.

The optimization problem that I am trying to solve is as follows:

[image]

where

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn import linear_model,metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_breast_cancer()
x = data.data
x = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(x)
y = np.sign(data.target.reshape(x.shape[0], 1) - 0.5)

c = 10
rho = 0.5
eta = 0.5
grad_tol = 1e-1

def l_h(z):
    return np.maximum(0, 1 - z)

def dl2_h(z):
    return -2 * l_h(z)

def obj(w, b, y, x):
    return (1/2) * np.linalg.norm(w)**2 + c * np.sum(l_h(y * (x@w+b))**2) 

def grad_w(w, b, y, x):
    return w + c * ((np.transpose(y) * np.transpose(x)) @ (dl2_h(y * (x@w+b))))
```

However whe I try to test my gradiant with the follwoing code I get two different answers:

```
w = np.random.normal(0,1,x.shape[1])
w = w.reshape((x.shape[1],1))
b = np.random.normal(0,1)

epsilon = np.zeros((x.shape[1],1)
epsilon[0] = 0.0001    
grad_estiamt = (obj(w + epsilon , b , y, x) - obj(w , b, y, x))/epsilon[0]
//compare grad_estimate with grad_w(w, b, y, x)[0]. They are not the same!!!
```

The values for the above two expressions should be very close if the gradient was right, but they are not. Can some one please tell me what where I am making a mistake?

Comment: What're `epsilon`, `y_t`, `x_t`, etc.?

Comment: Sorry for leaving these out: 'x_t = x[0].reshape(1, 30)
y_t = y[0]' and epsilon is a small number

Comment: if `epsilon` is a small number, what happens when you get to the last command with `epsilon[0]`? (Sorry in advance for the possibly-obvious questions!).

Comment: I have made a vector epsilon which is all zeros then I added a very small number to the first element of it. I want to estimate the partial derivative for the of the obj function with y_t and x_t and then compare it to the first element in the output of the grad_w with the input y_t and x_t. If my gradient implementation is correct these two should be very close, but they are not. My main question is do you think my implementation of the objective function and the gradient of it are correct?

Comment: I have edited the code to make myself more clear, and I have replaced y_t and x_t with y and x.